# How to make different video answers in list of questions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I need to make popup which have to contain questions and video answers.

The tricky part for me is how to make every question to display different video, but on the same place. Also when the user first sees the popup the first question and video should be predefined.

Here is the basic scheme of the popup:

[image: img:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set every video to `display:none`, then use jQuery to display the needed item once some user action is taken. In my example I used [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Basic example:

```js
$(".options>li").click(function() {
  $(".view").css('display', 'none')
});

$("li.aaa").click(function() {
  $(".view.aaa").css('display', 'block')
});

$("li.bbb").click(function() {
  $(".view.bbb").css('display', 'block')
});

$("li.ccc").click(function() {
  $(".view.ccc").css('display', 'block')
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
}

.panel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.view {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.options>li {
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
  list-style: none;
  margin: .25em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="panel right">
    <ul class="options">
      <li class="aaa">aaa</li>
      <li class="bbb">bbb</li>
      <li class="ccc">ccc</li>
      <li class="ddd"></li>
      <li class="eee"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="panel left">
    <img src="http://fruitandvegetablesmelbourne.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/golden-delicious-apples.jpg" class="view aaa">
    <img src="http://img.aws.livestrongcdn.com/ls-article-image-400/cpi.studiod.com/www_livestrong_com/photos.demandstudios.com/56/251/fotolia_5712687_XS.jpg" class="view bbb">
    <img src="http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-49502853,width-400,resizemode-4/49502853.jpg" class="view ccc">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @ihazcode Thank you it worked! But the answers of the question are in one video and do you know how to make the whole video to be cut in pieces, so when the answer of the first question is over to move to next question and became highlighted.